# Google not indexing my site at all

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

I am working on a site right now and it does not appear in the google search results at all.

I have submitted the url at : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url as well.

I have verified the ownership of my site using google's search console (I used the HTML file upload method). The verification was successful for the URL with `https` but it does not verify the URL with `http`.

At least it should show the website when search for it using the `site:` keyword. But it does not show anything.

Comment: How long has it been?? It takes days, weeks, and months.

Comment: I first submitted the url 2 months ago and I added my site in webmasters tool for verification about a month ago.

Comment: Use the Fetch as Google tool in the Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools) to see if there is a reason why Google cannot see your site. Also check to make sure you are not blocking it using robots.txt, a firewall, a bot block software, or other thing.

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc. I have tried the the 'Fetch as Google' tool. This is what it shows [link](http://i.imgur.com/y2q1mbj.png?1). Looks like the indexing request is in pending state. Do you think this is the reason?

Comment: It takes a few minutes to process.

Comment: Check to see if Google can see your robots.txt file in Search Console. I tried to fetch the robots.txt file and was redirected to the home page. This can be a problem - maybe. If you are using a CMS, make sure that it is not doing something stupid. You may need to post your .htaccess file (assuming Apache) along with your robots.txt file in your question.

Comment: I am not using a CMS. Its an ASP.Net application written from scratch. There is no robots.txt file there. Should I add an empty robots.txt file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31779/discussion-between-danish-and-closetnoc).

Comment: I am there... in chat...

Answer (score 2):

You have a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">` in your homepage. That will stop crawlers from indexing or following any of your links. Remove that and you should be okay.

Also, instead of a blank robots.txt file, add the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Comment: @Danish Trust Andrew. He is good!! Remove the meta tag and all should be okay. It may take a while for Google to notice it. I would recommend using Fetch as Google again. It takes a couple of days to really show up in the SERPs, but it could go a bit faster for you using this option. Cheers!!